# Can I use a column source more than once in a pivot table?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I have a massive sheet of data and trying to create a pivot table to extract data so I can create a graph from the results.

I have 2 columns with times in them and I would like to display the average, Max & Min time from each column in the pivot table.

I have created the pivot table from the data and formatted this showing the average time. But I can not find a way of duplicating this data to then show the Min & Max.

Is it possible or should I be using something else?

I am using Excel 2010

Comment: Yes you can add the column multiple times to the Values field and then change the "Summarize value field" option to Min, Max, and so on.

Comment: @BigBen First time using a Pivot table how do I add the duplicate ? I didn't know the terminology so I have been struggling a bit

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add the column multiple times to the *Values* area, and then change the "Summarize value field" option to Min, Max, Average, and so on.

As an example, this is a screenshot of the `Data` field inserted multiple times in the *Values* area. You can just drag the field in multiple times. Then:

1. Right-click on the field to bring up the *Value Field Settings*
2. Then change the *Summarize value field by* option to Min, Max, Average, etc.

[image]